# Вывод целочисленного числа в формате 1 111 111 111 через цикл. Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, циклы

Допустим, есть любое **Int** число *n* (отрицательное в том числе). Его надо вернуть в формате 1 111 111 в тип **String**. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ сделать это через цикл, но не трогая массивы ? Видел только подобные формулы на форуме, но они лишь разворачивают число. А мне надо получить мое же введенное число, но с отступами.

```
for (; number > 0;number /= 10){
        number_create = number % 10;
    }
```

Comment: Просто пробелы между разрядами?

Comment: @wigravy Да, только пробелы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов решения:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int number = 1111111;
        System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("###,###").format(number).toString().replace(',',' '));
    }
}
```

Вывод:
1 111 111

Ещё такой вариант:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;


public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
        symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
        df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
        int i = 1111111;
        System.out.println(df.format(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Это отличный способ, подходит под любое число, но вместо пробелов у меня битые символы. Кодировку не проходит. Если это как то фиксануть, то это решение будет идеальным. Есть идеи ?

Comment: @Tokamo а если заменить так `replace(',','\u0020')`

Comment: К сожалению, тоже самое. Кодировка у меня UTF-8. На какой бы я символ не поменял, будет выдавать непонятный символ вопроса

Comment: @Tokamo вы где код пишите в какой ide? Правильно ли настроена кодировка файла?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA. ver 2020.3.2.0. В настройках кодировки везде стоит UTF-8

Comment: @Tokamo `Settings` → `Editor` → `File Encodings` → `Project Encoding` установите это на `UTF-8`

Comment: У меня так и стоит. Все равно не работает

Comment: @Tokamo В файлах Idea IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition...\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions и idea64.exe.vmoptions, также доступные через Help->Edit Custom VM Options..., добавить строки -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 и -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8 и затем перезапустите IDE

Comment: Все, этот способ помог. Огромнейшее спасибо

Comment: @Tokamo Рад,что всё получилось :) Примите мой ответ пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Для этого не нужны циклы и не надо парсить число вручную. Существует способ проще:

```
    Integer number = 123456;
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    System.out.println(nf.format(number));
```

Comment: У вас на выходе: `123,456`, нужны ведь пробелы в качестве разделителей

Comment: @nikoshi на выходе получается то, что вы хотите, а разделитель зависит от локации, которую можно задать в аргументах getInstance()

Comment: Какую локацию нужно задать в `getInstance()`, чтобы `format()` в качестве разделителей применял пробелы?

Comment: Уже разобрался. Такой вариант `NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("ru", "RU"))` сработает

Comment: @nikoshi да, все верно, для русской локации это пробелы, а запятые вроде для английской, но это можно посмотреть в доках

Answer (score 0):

Или такой вариант

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class tt {
    public static void customFormat(String pattern, int value) {
          DecimalFormat myForm = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
          String output = myForm.format(value);
          System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          customFormat("###, ###, ###", 1111111);  
    }
}
```

Comment: более гибкий метод, куда запятую поставишь, там и будет разделитель. плюс с double работает   customFormat("###,###.###", 123456.789);

Comment: У вас на выходе: `1,111,111`, нужны пробелы в качестве разделителей

Comment: не... ну если прям настолько знания отсутствуют, то конечно)))

Comment: Можно ли задать с помощью `DecimalFormat` пробелы в качестве разделителей? Было бы полезно увидеть

Comment: разве ответ помеченный галочкой не использует DecimalFormat ???)))

Comment: ок) я подумал может есть вариант обойтись лишь `DecimalFormat`

Comment: кодировки разные. у меня пробелы выдает.